# How can I get to see the full image in the background?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

At the bottom there are two images, unfortunately these images can not be seen completely.

You can open the original image in a new tab to see exactly how it looks.

To me it sees about 90% of image

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="entry-content" style="height: 391px;">
        <div class="sus"></div>
        <div class="jos"></div>
        <div class="jos2"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.sus{
  width:100%;
  height: 60%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BANNER-300x215.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size:cover;
}

.jos{
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS2-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jos2{
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:url("http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NEWS1-300x246.png") no-repeat center center #B03D3D;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

So I thought to do pictures ... you tell me please what is wrong and how to fix the situation so the image to see full?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see complete image!! Not sure what's happening with you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 100% `background-size` like,

```
.jos{
   ...
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.jos2{
   ....
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the full image change your CSS :

instead of `background-size: cover;` use `background-size: contain;` then you'll see it completely.

The problem is that then the image has borders on the left and right.

Comment: and how to remove this curb?

Comment: Edit the image and scale it to fit your container proportions as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `background-size` css property with value `cover` does not show you the complete image.

*Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.
     Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area- source :[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)*

So if you need full image use

`background-size:100% 100%;`

**Live Demo @W3Schools :http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover**